# Getting the User's Username - Google+ Sign In JS

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I am making a social network, where you don't *have* to sign in, and I'm putting in a G+ Sign In button. When you sign in, I want to get the username to put it into the name field. I have thought about this, and I think I came up with an answer. I asked a different question concerning getting the email, and it was a scope URL.

**The question is, what is the scope URL, or what do you have to do to get the username?**

Answer (score 0):

As documented [here](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#scopes), the scope to view profile data, including the User ID and Display name is called "profile" or "userinfo.profile"

```
// This sample assumes a client object has been created.
// To learn more about creating a client, check out the starter:
//  https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/javascript
var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
  'userId' : 'me'
});

request.execute(function(resp) {
  console.log('ID: ' + resp.id);
  console.log('Display Name: ' + resp.displayName);
  console.log('Image URL: ' + resp.image.url);
  console.log('Profile URL: ' + resp.url);
});
```

You can have a look at code samples and usage further, over here: https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get#response